# Lie derivative of vielbein along Killing vector

Tags: differential-geometry

We know that a vector $X$ is killing if the Lie derivative of the metric along $X$ vanishes:

$\mathcal{L}_X (g_{mn})=0$

We also know that the metric can be written in terms of the vielbeins:

$g_{mn}=\eta_{ab}e^a_m e^b_n$.

So is it true that if $\mathcal{L}_X (g_{mn})=0$ then it implies that $\mathcal{L}_X (e^{a})=0$. If so then how do I derive the later from the former?

Here $e^a$ is the one-form:

$e^a=e^a_m dx^m$.

Answer (score 1):

No - even when $g$ is flat you can twist your frame. In Minkowski space $g= -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ define $$e_0 = (1,0,0,0)\\ e_1 = (0, \cos z, \sin z,0)\\ e_2 = (0,-\sin z, \cos z,0)\\ e_3=(0,0,0,1)$$.

Clearly $X = \partial/\partial z$ is Killing for $g$, but $e^1 = \cos z\ dx - \sin z\ dy$ has Lie derivative $\mathcal L_X e^1 = -\sin z\ dx - \cos z\ dy.$

Comment: Ok thanks. This helps!